# One MySQL query for taking the substr of two fields combined without concat on the full fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substr

table: field1, field2

given offset & len i want the result to be:

```
select substr(concat(field1,field2),offset,len) from table
```

since field1 and field2 are large varchars and this query is a bottleneck i don't want to continually concat the two large fields together and would rather do something along the lines of

```
select case when (offset+len) < length(field1) then substr(field1,offset,len) else....
```

there are three distinct situations: 1) a substr of field1, 2) a substr of field2 3) a substr(field1) concat'd with a substr(field2)

anybody have a solution to this brainteaser? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has an `IF` function which would make the query clearer than with the CASE struct.

Any way you write it, it's expensive. Why not create another column (go redundancy!) and save the right values there? Redundancy isn't a problem these days and it's much, much faster than any kind of concat, case or if.

(If `offset` isn't static, this is no solution. If `offset` is, but `len` isn't, it **is** still a solution.)

Comment: offset is variable len is static